# Ultimate subproject sbt setup

Tags: java, scala, build, sbt

I'm working on some code with several sub-projects many of which depend on each other. For example, there's a `utils` project with various utilities, a `queueing` project with some code for managing queues of things, and then a `mainApp` project. The `queueing` project depends on `utils`, and `mainApp` depends on both `utils` and `queueing`. There are many more projects in addition, but hopefully you get the general idea.

We use to have a standard sbt submodule setup for this with one root build file, lots of sub-projects and the standard `aggregate` and `dependsOn` stuff. This worked, but was problematic:

- It could be very slow to build and run tests for the project. Building everyting takes about 15 minutes and unit testing everything takes even longer.
- Due to the way aggregate works, unit testing `mainApp` resulted in runs of all tests in `utils` and `queuing` even if they hadn't changed. True, you can do "test-quick" but that stops working when you change git branches and such so you still end up running the whole test suite often.
- While sbt does let you build just a subproject, you have to be in the root directory and remember to qualify the build. For example, you have to remember to run `sbt utils/compile` rather than `sbt compile`.

So we switched to completely separate project and separate git repos. Each project builds and then deploys an artifact to Nexus. Thus, to build and test the `mainApp` you build just it and it pulls already compiled .jar files for the other projects from the nexus server. This makes it easier to work in just one project, but it becomes harder to make a change to, for example, utils and then use it in `mainApp`. Specifically, you often want to do something like add a method to `utils` and then immediately test that method in `mainApp` to see if it worked before pushing a new version of `utils`. But now, to do that, you have to:

- Add your code to utils
- Bump the version number in utils
- Run "sbt publish-loca"
- Edit the build.sbt in `mainApp` and add `-SNAPSHOT` to the `utils` dependency
- Run `sbt update`
- Build and test `mainApp`

If that all works, you then have to push `utils` and `mainApp` in the right order to the continuous build server and be sure to wait for the `utils` build to complete before you push `mainApp`.

Even worse, maintaining the versioning becomes really complicated. Suppose we start with all projects at version 1.0 and depending on version 1.0 of the other projects. Now suppose we find a bug in `utils` that affects `mainApp`. So we fix `utils`, change its version number to 1.1, update `mainApp` to depend on 1.1 and re-build. Suppose the code that fixed the bug in `mainApp` introduces a bug in `queue`. The problem is that if you go to `queue` and run its tests, they'll run against version 1.0 of `utils` (even if you use ranges as sbt only re-checks those periodically). However, when you build `mainApp` there will be a dependency conflict on `utils` which sbt will resolve. No matter how it resolves it, it will be "wrong" for at least one project. We can set the resolver to "strict" but then managing versions becomes very labor intensive across the 10+ projects.

What I'm really looking for is a build setup that is the best of both worlds. Specifically:

- I have a root dir with sub-dirs for each project
- If `pwd` is one of those sub-dirs all sbt commands refer to just that project. So, if `pwd` is `queue`, then `sbt test` compiles and tests **only** `queue`.
- If there's a version of an artifact in Nexus, it is pulled from there, but if there's more recent code on the disk, the dependency is built locally and that is used instead.

Or something like that. Does anyone have any advice on how to set this up with sbt?

Comment: Concerning your point that "you have to remember to run `sbt utils/compile` rather than `sbt compile`", you could open an `sbt` command line, type `project utils`, and run all your (unprefixed) commands there.